# How do I access the element of a 2D array in the following scenario?

Tags: python, arrays

If I have a 2d array

```
mylist=[[0],[0],[1],[0]]
for idx in range(len(mylist)):
    element=mylist[idx]
```

`element=list([0])` for the first element and second element, `element=list([1])` for the third element and so on in the same pattern

For example, how do I make `element=0` instead of `element=list([0])` in the first instance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to access elements in a 2D array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022211/how-to-access-elements-in-a-2d-array)

Comment: Doesn't really help explain this particular problem for me

Comment: Why don't you directly iterate on `list` instead of using `range` like `for i in mylist: print(i[0])`

Comment: Just do `element=mylist[idx][0]`?

Answer (score 0):

It is not very clear from your question what you are trying to achieve so I am going to outline several scenarios for you.

1. As mentioned by @AkshayNevrekar it might be worth going through [how to access elements in a 2D array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022211/how-to-access-elements-in-a-2d-array);

```
mylist=[[0],[0],[1],[0]] 
  for i in range(len(mylist)):   
    for j in range(len(mylist[i])):
      print(mylist[i][j])
```

2. Did you choose the right data structure for your problem? It might be worth keeping the items in 1D list.

   ```
   mylist=[0, 0, 1, 0]
   ```

Or alternatively list of tuples, access would be the same as option 1:

```
mylist = [(0, 0, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1, 1)]
```