# What does this code fragment print? More specifically, what does the 2 in A[0][2] refer to?

Tags: python

`A = [[2, 3, 1, 0], [3, 1, 0], [0, 2]]`
`print(A[A[0][2]][2])`

I understand that A[0] evaluates to [2, 3, 1, 0]. I don't understand how to evaluate A[0][2] though. If someone could explain, it'd be much appreciated!

Comment: A[0][2] should evaluate to 1. 0 stands for first array and 2 stands for the 3rd element on that array.

Comment: What happens when you try it for yourself? What does `A[0][2]` print out? Then what does `A[A[0][2]]` print out? Etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to access elements in a 2D array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022211/how-to-access-elements-in-a-2d-array)

Comment: That makes sense now, I didn't know the syntax. Thank you so much!

Comment: so if A[0][2] yields to 1, then expression of A[A[0][2]][2] will yield A[1][2] that refers 3rd element of the second array which is 0.thats why you see 0 in the output

Comment: Thank you Ali. That really helps

Answer (score 1):

In your case `A` is a nested list (a list of lists). When you do `A[0]` you access the first element in your list which happens to be `[2, 3, 1, 0]` as you understood. However this element is itself a list, which means you can also access it's inner elements the exact same way. In your case you want to access the element in the position N°2 within list `[2,3,1,0]` which is `1`

```
Step 1: A[0] ==> [2,3,1,0]
Step 2: A[0][2] ==> [2,3,1,0][2] ==> 1
```

Your final print is a bit more complicated but the idea is the same.

```
A[
   A[0][2]
 ][2]
```

```
Step 1: What is A[A[0][2]] ==> I see that I have to find out what A[0][2]...
Step 2: Solve A[0][2] ==> 1
Step 3: My request becomes A[1]
Step 4: Solve A[1] ==> [3, 1, 0]
Step 5: Now I need to figure out what [3,1,0][2] is
Step 6: Solve it ==> 0
```

So in the end `A[A[0][2]][2] ==> 0`.

Answer (score 0):

In multi-dimension arrays mapping goes like this:

let `A=[[0, 1], ['a', 'b'], [0, 1]]`

So if `A[0] = [0, 1]` then `A[0][0] = 0`

and if `A[1] = ['a', 'b']` then `A[1][0] = 'a'` and `A[1][1] = 'b'`

So, in your case:
`A = [[2, 3, 1, 0], [3, 1, 0], [0, 2]]`

if `A[0] = [2, 3, 1, 0]` then `A[0][2] = 1`

which means `A[A[0][2]][2]` can be written as `A[1][2]` i.e. 0