# Algorithm To Solve 5 x 5 Number Game

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, numpy

I have been trying to create an algorithm to solve [5x5 Number Game](https://teacher.desmos.com/activitybuilder/custom/5fda5f43b09baf0cec6fc0a2)(click for rules and scoring). However I have been stuck because I do not know how to figure out the best position to figure out where the number goes. So far I figured to calculate the score but cannot progress further. The crappy code I came up so far is:

```py
import numpy as np
import random

# i could use an array to represent board but im more familiar with nested lists
# when i get the vertical score i do have to represent it as a array to do that math
board = [[1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

# gets the score horizontally
def getHorizontalScore(board):
  score = 0
  # i know it is inefficient but this is what i came up with inorder to figure this out
  for list in board:
    i_zero = list.count(0)
    i_one = list.count(1)
    i_two = list.count(2)
    i_three = list.count(3)
    i_four = list.count(4)
    i_five = list.count(5)
    i_six = list.count(6)
    i_seven = list.count(7)
    i_eight = list.count(8)
    i_nine = list.count(9)
    i_ten = list.count(10)
    if i_zero > 1:
      score += 0 * i_zero
    if i_one > 1:
      score += i_one
    if i_two > 1:
      score += i_two * 2
    if i_three > 1:
      score += i_three * 3
    if i_four > 1:
      score += i_four * 4
    if i_five > 1:
      score += i_five * 5
    if i_six > 1:
      score += i_six * 6
    if i_seven > 1:
      score += i_seven * 7
    if i_eight > 1:
      score += i_eight * 8
    if i_nine > 1:
      score += i_nine * 9
    if i_ten > 1:
      score += i_ten * 10
  return score

# gets the score verticaly (hopefully)
def getVerticalScore(board):
  # represent board as an array
  board = np.asarray(board)
  #score
  score = 0
  # i know it is inefficient but this is what i came up with inorder to figure this out
  # board.T is so useful praise numpy for adding this feature
  for column in board.T:
    i_one = list(column).count(1)
    i_two = list(column).count(2)
    i_three = list(column).count(3)
    i_four = list(column).count(4)
    i_five = list(column).count(5)
    i_six = list(column).count(6)
    i_seven = list(column).count(7)
    i_eight = list(column).count(8)
    i_nine = list(column).count(9)
    i_ten = list(column).count(10)
    if i_one > 1:
      score += i_one
    if i_two > 1:
      score += i_two * 2
    if i_three > 1:
      score += i_three * 3
    if i_four > 1:
      score += i_four * 4
    if i_five > 1:
      score += i_five * 5
    if i_six > 1:
      score += i_six * 6
    if i_seven > 1:
      score += i_seven * 7
    if i_eight > 1:
      score += i_eight * 8
    if i_nine > 1:
      score += i_nine * 9
    if i_ten > 1:
      score += i_ten * 10
    return score


def getScore(board):
  return getVerticalScore(board) + getHorizontalScore(board)
  
def displayBoard(board):
  for list in board:
    print(list)
```

If someone could help me figure out how to make the algorithm and compact my code a bit, please help me.

Comment: Your implementation gives the wrong result when calculating the score. For example, it would consider a score if you have repeated numbers on a row but not adjacent. Regarding the goal to write an algorithm to solve the game: if the numbers are not all known at the beginning, it will not be solvable (at least not exactly). But I think your should go and try to have at least a correct scoring implementation first before getting into that complexity.

Comment: The way I get the score is kind of inefficient however it does work. I use a list of 5 nested lists to represent the board. You can try it out for yourself, I gave it a few boards and it worked. @RodrigoRodrigues

Answer (score 1):

Your score calculation for row and column is off.

Let's take this board as an example:

```py
board = [[7, 7, 2, 3, 7],     # 14
         [6, 6, 2, 3, 3],     # 18
         [2, 4, 2, 8, 8],     # 16
         [1, 10, 9, 5, 8],    # 0
         [10, 10, 10, 5, 8]]  # 30
#          0  20  6  16  24
# total score = 144
```

If I use your `getScore()` function I get 89 instead of 144

The code you're using to get multiples doesn't consider if the numbers are adjacent to each other or not:

```py
for list in board:
#   ...
    i_seven = list.count(7) # this will return 3 although only 2 7's are adjacent
```

In this case it is better for you to use indices to traverse through your board. See this answer about [accessing elements in nested list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7022294/20163209).

```py
# Getting each element per row
for row in board:
   for pos in range(5):
      row_num = row[pos]

# Getting each element per column
for col in range(5):
   for pos in range(5):
      col_num = board[pos][col]
```

You don't need to count the 0's as they indicate an empty field on your board. So your algorithm knows that it's legal to place a new number on a field.